# Chart.js doughnut and pie chart at same canvas mixed

Tags: charts, chart.js, pie-chart

Can I display together two different types of chart together. I need to have a doughnut chart with about 70%, and another pie chart section over the first (doughnut) chart that will be just a thin line going from center of the circle to the doughnut's edge. I want to make a speed-o-meter this way.

Answer (score 1):

A pie chart is a doughnut chart with `cutoutPercentage:0`. Try using a doughnut chart, setting `cutoutPercentage:0`, and adding two datasets.

Comment: Thanks, this is true generally, but for my case, I need one dataset to be pie and the other one doughnut. I tried, but I could not find a way to set different cutoutPercentage for each dataset.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you're trying to do? It's not clear to me